# Position absolute div with reference to its parent parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have structure of three nested div

```
<div id="div1"> 
   <div id="div2">     // has come content
      <div id="div3"> 
                        // has some content with a form
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

All three div are absolute.Now I want the `#div3` to be positioned according to `#div1`
if I `#div3` is `right:0px;` then it should go to the right most of `#div1`

**Note** Please Don't ask to Correct the structure as it not developed by me and `#div1` and `#div2` are not in my control.

only Idea I have is to move the `#div3` and append it to `#div1` by jQuery.but I will like to have a pure `CSS` solution if possible. else i will go with the `jQuery append`

I thought I have explained well css will not be required. but hear it is 
**CSS**

```
#div1 {
position: absolute;
display: none;
}

#div2 
{
position: absolute;
top: 85px;
left: 56px;
width: 300px;
z-index: 2;
}

#div3 {//what ever you want to write to make it relative to #div1  }
```

Comment: And here it is: what have you tried?

Comment: What CSS is currently being applied? As the three divs are positioned absolutely, div 3 will be positioned relative to div 2. To make it right aligned to div 1, then div2 must have a width or position that places it's right border up against div 1's right border.

Comment: the css and html is large i cant post it hear so i have to tried to make a small scale example

Comment: The description is confusing, a real world example would help.

Comment: If #div1 has 'display:none', then div2 and div3 will also be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position()` method to get `DIV2` position relative to it's parent `DIV1` and use those values as negative in order to make DIV 3 appear to be in div1.

Following should place `DIV3` in top left corner of `DIV1`

```
var div2Pos= $('#div2').position();
$('#div3').css({top: 0-div2Pos.top, left: 0-div2Pos.left})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/q5RgZ/1

Another simple solution would be to move div3 out of div2 and place in div1

```
$('#div3').appendTo('#div1')
```

Answer (score 2):

If the position of `div3` is absolute, it'll look in his ancestors until it finds a parent that's relatively positioned. To achieve what you want you'd need:

```
#div1 { position: relative; }
#div2 { position: static; } // default positioning for DIVs
#div3 { position: absolute; right: 0; }
```

Comment: I already said that its not possible to alter the css od `#div1` and `#div2`

Answer (score -1):

Setting `#div1` position to relative should do the trick. But if using `position:absolute` in `#div1` is required, then the element containing these three div tags should use `position:relative` . Like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1"> 
     <div id="div2">     // has come content
        <div id="div3"> 
                        // has some content with a form
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}
```